# How can i solve an error in R with quadprog::solve.QP?

Tags: r

i am trying to run this code but i am getting the following error

" Error in quadprog::solve.QP(C, -d, t(H), f, meq = meq) :
matrix D in quadratic function is not positive definite!
In addition: Warning message:
In pracma::quadprog(C, d, NULL, NULL, Aeq, beq, lb, ub) : "

The code is:

```
min_constrain <- function(sigma) {
 
 n_row <- nrow(sigma)
 
 
 Aeq <- matrix(1, nrow = 1, ncol = n_row)
 
 beq <- 1
 
 lb <- matrix(0, nrow = 1, ncol = n_row)
 ub <- matrix(1, nrow = 1, ncol = n_row)
 
 C <- sigma
 d <- rep(0, n_row)
 
 w <- pracma::quadprog(C, d, NULL, NULL, Aeq, beq, lb, ub)
 
 out <- list(weight = w$xmin)
 
 return(out)
 
}
```

and the sigma value is :

[sigma value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMprt.jpg)

Thks for the help

Comment: Please read the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and, in particular, note that it asks that you NOT use images since no one wants to retype all that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.